# Using a typedef defined inside a templated typename

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to use a type **Y** which has been defined by a typedef inside of another type **X**, from within a third *templated* type **Z**, where **X** acts as a template parameter to **Z**?

This (non-compiling) pseudocode illustrates the desired behaviour:

```
struct X {
  typedef float Y;
};

template<typename T>
struct Z {
  void DoSomething(T::Y with_this);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to let the compiler know that `T::Y` is a type because it depends on `T`:

```
void DoSomething(typename T::Y with_this);
```

Comment: In case you are curious, this is because C++ wants to parse the template before it knows what `T` is.  Without knowing what `T` is `T::X` could be a member function, a `enum` value, or a static member.  To make it non ambiguous we are required to say 'type incoming' with `typename`.